# Keep a:active on while person is on the page?

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, navigation

go to http://planetminecraft.com and when you look at the links you can see they stay shaded when your are on the page that link reffers to.

I would like to do the same thing but with black background not shadow. Here is my html and css

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Testing layouts</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="maincontainer">

<ul>
    <li><a href="#servers">SERVERS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#skins">SKINS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#resource-packs">RESOURCE PACKS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#builds">BUILDS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#mods">MODS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#forum">FORUM</a></li>
</ul>

Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text
Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text
Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text
Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text
Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text
Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text
Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text Testing text

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #A3A3A3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #7D7D7D, #7D7D7D 50px, transparent 57px,   transparent 140%);
}
#maincontainer {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 960px;
  min-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: ridge;
  border-color: #919191;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.35);
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
padding-top: 6px;
}

li {
float:left;
margin-right: 12px;
border: groove;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #969696;
}

a {
display:block;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
height: 38px;
background-color:#7D7D7D;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 37px;
color: #EDEDED;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: impact;
font-size: 1.8em;
}

li:hover {
float:left;
margin-right: 12px;
border: ridge;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: #969696;
}

a:hover {
color: white;
}

a:active {
background-color: black;
}
```

You only need to look at the a `a:hover a:active li li:hover ul`

Also is this possible with CSS or does it need JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [solution](http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/highlighting-current-page-with-css) of what you are looking for. No JS needed.